# Justifying a cryptic question: find $x$ if $x-5=11$ and $x+5=9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A cryptic question being asked on the Social Media:
$$\text{Find}~ X,~~
 \text{if}~ X-5=11, ~\text{and}~ X+5=9.~~~~(1)$$
is mathematically vague. But an interesting answer given is 16 and it refers to a clock with two hands when it shows 4 O'clock.

I find that using mod(modular)-arithmetic we can justify it.
By M(mod N) we mean the remainder when the  M is divided by N.
For instance: 17(mod 15)=2, 12(mod 15)=-3 or 12 so on and so forth.

This way the cryptic equation (1) become a sensible mod-equation as

X(mod 12)-5(mod 12)=11(mod 12)

and

X(mod 12)+5(mod 12)=9(mod 12)

$\implies$ X=16.

The question is: Am I right?

Comment: If that is what is meant by the question, sure. I stopped engaging intentionally vague, sensational and/or controversial math questions on social media, I would suggest you to do the same. Only point is to attract attention and they don't care about anything else.

Comment: When I saw this question I failed to guess I searched in the internet, only the the question was there without any answer or explanation. In my group someone answered it as 4' O'clock, then it occurred to me. Thanks for your comment. Cheers!

Comment: They would also be congruent mod 2,3,4, or 6.

Comment: Oh! yes, precisely speaking.

Comment: Assuming $=$ in the question really means $\equiv \pmod{12},$ then $X$ could be $16,$ or $28,$ or $4,$ or $-8,$ or any of an infinite number of integer values. Personally, if I had to choose just one of those values I would choose $4.$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In any number system ([ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics))) the following equivalences hold true  $$\begin{align} &x\!-\!5=11,\ x\!+\!5= 9\\[.3em]
\iff\  \, &\ 11\!+\!5\,=\, x\, =\, 9\!-\!5\\[.4em] 
\smash{\overset{{\rm subtract}\ 4}\iff}\ \  &\ \ \ \ \ \color{#c00}{12} = x\!-\!4 = \color{#c00}0\end{align}\qquad$$

So your equations have a solution in a ring $\iff \color{#c00}{12 = 0}\,$ in the ring. For example, they are solvable in $\,\Bbb Z_n =\,$  ring of [integers $\bmod n\,$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) where $\,n\,$ divides $\, 12,\,$ i.e. $\, n = 2,3,4,6,12,\,$ as well as any rings containing such $\,\Bbb Z_n$ (i.e. [$\Bbb Z_n$-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Generalization:_algebra_over_a_ring)) e.g. rings of polynomials, power series and matrices over $\,\Bbb Z_n$.

In any such ring the equations have *unique* solution $\,x = 4.\, $ Note that your solution is identical because  $16 = \color{#c00}{12}+4 = \color{#c00}0+4 = 4\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{12 = 0}\,$ in every such ring.